# Do we really need an "untagged" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have an [untagged](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, which I think should not exist. What do people think? If we DO decide to remove the tag, is there any way to prevent it from showing up again?

Comment: [tag:untagged] emerges when questions are migrated here from other sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [untagged](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is created by the system automatically typically when the Moderators delete tags from the system. Questions *using* that tag may end up without any tags at all. That requires a bit of cleanup.

*Untagged* questions should be given proper tags. That's how you get rid of the 'untagged' label; search for them and tag them properly.